# php insert blob into mysql from base64 string

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

I knew that there are several similar questions, also I am aware that best practice is to keep images on server but I was told to do this way... Well I am sending base64 string from android to php webservice. I am sending it right, also tested via Postman to be sure that problem is not android but service. I have error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'oX?ë–§?=j?b?ED?NÏ¯??=?|?pv??Ñ‘Qv}gX?' at line 2**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
    require_once '../config/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $host_id = $_POST['host_id'];
    $name = $_POST['event_name'];
    $description = $_POST['event_description'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $photo = $_POST['photo'];
    // get all products from products table
    $escaped = mysql_escape_string ($photo);
    $photo_blob = base64_decode($escaped);

    //echo $photo_blob;

    $result = mysql_query(
    'INSERT INTO dogadjaj (host_id, name, description, date, photo) 
    VALUES ("' . $host_id . '" ,"' . $name .'", "' . $description . '", "' . $date . '", "' . $photo_blob . '");')
    or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: First, stop using the `mysql_*` functions.  They've been deprecated for a long time and removed in PHP7.  Second, learn about prepared statements.  You are currently vulnerable to SQL injection.  Third, why would you run `mysql_escape_string()` _before_ `base64_decode()`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: You would use `base64_encode();` not  `base64_decode();` to generate a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @JohnB.Walugembe, ouch. I don't knew why I put that.... That was answer. :) Many thanks!!!

Comment: Ok thanks, I had deleted the full answer and used a comment because I was not sure. I have now undeleted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$photo_blob = base64_encode($escaped);` instead of `$photo_blob = base64_decode($escaped);`.  You would need the `base64_decode` when processing the `base_64` read from the database.